# How to remove tab from TabItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to remove the button on the Tab menu, but there does not seem to be anything in the properties that will allow this,

[image]

I don't have much thus far as I have been trying remove the button on the tab first, this below just stops you from clicking the tab and anything on it, I want to make it transparent or remove it completely if possible.

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
```

This below makes the whole `TabControl` transparent, which defeats the purpose of the container,

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
```

This is the XAML I have thus far,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

Is there a way to do this? Or am I stuck with these tab buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the `TabControl`, it is the `TabItem` control that needed to be worked on.

This code hides the Tab Buttons and all borders,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: @mm8, Yes, I have made a whole heap of buttons in a side menu and I did not want the ones across the top. Why do you ask?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that your issue has been solved.